# Joomla keep showing home page whenever I navigate to any article

Tags: joomla

I have moved Joomla 2.5 from local WAMP server to my website which runs under windows OS with Apache server installed, home page is loading successfully but whenever I choose any article I got the URL changed in browser's address bar but it keeps showing me the home page.
I checked permissions, the configuration file is writable and successfully connects to database also all articles and categories are shown in administrator area,
PHP 5.2.17,
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are all your joomla seo settings enabled? If yes than did you rename your htaccess.txt file to .htaccess? Try switching off sef urls in Global configuration and then check. Also in configuration.php file check if there is any value for live_site.

Comment: @AmitRay Well... Something has changed after I added live_site value, the URLs become like:
`http://almoheetgroup.com/site/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2:2016-12-24-15-01-23&catid=9:news&Itemid=107`
but empty page my configurations:
` public $live_site = 'http://almoheetgroup.com/site/Joomla';
 public $sef = '0';
 public $sef_rewrite = '1';
 public $sef_suffix = '1';
 public $unicodeslugs = '0';
 `public $log_path = 'D:\\Inetpub\\vhosts\\almoheetgroup.com\\httpdocs/logs';`
 `public $tmp_path = 'D:\\Inetpub\\vhosts\\almoheetgroup.com\\httpdocs/tmp';`
any ideas?

Comment: In addition, when I enable `$sef_suffix` the response is "page not found"

Comment: you have problem with sef urls. Just switch off all sef features in configuration.php file and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this problem is because of you have no menu item which has link to your content.
try this:
`Go to "main menu" and add a menu item, after that select an article for menu item and publish it.`
 it must solve the problem